# How to have a You Tube video play right on a page of my site?

Tags: youtube-api, html5-video

The page is http://www.rcblue.com/Music/YouTube/YouTube.htm 
I'd like the Ligeti video, http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature...&v=ECC6l7fAhJQ , to appear at about 400x550 size at the very top of the page. It should show one image of the video and have that big right-pointing triangle to click to start the video.

How should I code this (in HTML5)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
<iframe width="550" height="400" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ECC6l7fAhJQ?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I think you may have missed the `http:` in the `src` attribute.

Comment: Works great as is! Thanks very much, CodingWay.